# Why does PySpark select statement complain about ambiguous columns?

Tags: apache-spark, select, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, ambiguous

I wrote the following code to test (spark 3.2.1) how I can resolve multiple columns with the same name (spark is the spark session):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [['model 1', 10],
        ['model 1', 20],
        ['model 1', 10],
        ['model 2', 11],
        ['model 2', 21],
        ['model 2', 21],
        ]
data = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['model', 'capacity_bytes'])
capacity_counts = data.groupby('model', 'capacity_bytes').agg(F.count("*").alias('capacity_occurrence_count'))
capacity_counts_max = capacity_counts.groupby('model').agg(F.max('capacity_occurrence_count').alias('capacity_occurrence_count_max'))
conds = (capacity_counts['model']==capacity_counts_max['model']) & (capacity_counts['capacity_occurrence_count']==capacity_counts_max['capacity_occurrence_count_max'])
# res = capacity_counts.alias('capacity_counts').join(capacity_counts_max.alias('capacity_counts_max'), on=conds)
res = capacity_counts_max.join(capacity_counts, on=conds)

# fails with pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:  Column model#18 are ambiguous
res.select(capacity_counts['model'],'capacity_bytes').show()

# succeeds
res.select(capacity_counts_max['model'],'capacity_bytes').show()
```

I cannot understand why one of the select statements succeeds and the other one fails. I am aware that I can use an alias for the dataframes, but I still do not understand the above behaviour.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is a very good question. IMO, it may be a bug. I don't see any reason why it should work like this. However, if your intention is just to make the code work (as opposed to find out why this happens), use aliases on dataframes, as explained in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me , I don't think so t should fail as you are explicitly referring `model1` from capacity_counts - capacity_counts['model']

```py
res = capacity_counts_max.join(capacity_counts, on=conds)
res.show()
```

```py
res.select(capacity_counts['model'],'capacity_bytes').show()
# +-------+--------------+
# |  model|capacity_bytes|
# +-------+--------------+
# |model 2|            21|
# |model 1|            10|
# +-------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. It does fail with spark 3.2.1.

Comment: It is indeed failing. This explicitness is not guaranteed. I have seen cases when you have several columns of the same name and you explicitly tell which column to select, the first column is always selected no matter what you specify. But this was supposed to be fixed in Spark 3.2...